# Dagger2 splitting app in several gradle modules

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have following dagger components structure:

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = CoreModule.class)
public interface CoreComponent{
    ComponentA plus(ModuleA module);

    ComponentB plus(ModuleB module);
}

@ActivityScope @Subcomponent(modules = ModuleA.class)
public interface ComponentA {
    ComponentA inject(FragmentA fragment);
}

@ActivityScope @Subcomponent(modules = ModuleB.class)
public interface ComponentA {
    ComponentB inject(FragmentB fragment);
}
```

And client code looks like these:

```
class FragmentA extends Fragment{
    public FragmentA(){
        App.getCoreComponent().plus(new ModuleA()).inject(this);
    }
}
```

I've decided to split the application into several gradle modules. 
I would like to have gradle `Core` module and 2 modules `A` and `B` that depends on the core but doesn't know about each other.

My problem is that `CoreComponent` uses imports from `A` and `B` in order to create subcomponents. So `Core` is dependent on `A` and `B`.

I was trying to solve it using `@Components.Builder` but that also requires having dagger module in root component with a set of all subcomponents.

Is there any way how to remove the dependency of root component on its subcomponents.

*By dependency of the root component I mean that it should know about all subcomponents, that use it.*

According to dagger documentation:

> Subcomponents are components that inherit and extend the object graph
>   of a parent component. You can use them to partition your
>   application’s object graph into subgraphs either to **encapsulate
>   different parts of your application** from each other or to use more
>   than one scope within a component.
>
> An object bound in a subcomponent can depend on any object that is
>   bound in its parent component or any ancestor component, in addition
>   to objects that are bound in its own modules. On the other hand,
>   objects bound in parent components can’t depend on those bound in
>   subcomponents; nor can objects bound in one subcomponent depend on
>   objects bound in sibling subcomponents.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to remove dependency `CoreComponent -> ComponentA, ComponentB` using subcomponents. This is just not the way subcomponents work.

You could try to reverse this dependency by making `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` depend upon `CoreComponent` (`ComponentA, ComponentB -> CoreComponent`). This will require that you explicitly export objects in `CoreComponent`.

As a side note I must warn you that what you're trying to do will probably cause a big headache in the future: coupling internal implementations of modules through third party framework is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I thought about changing my subcomponents to components, but I don't want to explicitly show all of the dependencies, since the real app is huge and there would be much more dependencies.

Comment: @RostyslavRoshak I can't give you any specific advice, but in general I would try to remove  `Dagger` related code from all modules except the "top" one. I would also try to partition my logic in such a way that dependencies between "gradle modules" are uni-directional (i.e. if `Core` module depends on `A`, `A` will not be dependent on `Core`)